# I am making a lightsaber , how can i bend the cylinder to be straight in the middle for the armor?

Tags: modeling, modifiers, objects, bezier-curves

[image]

I tried to make the cylinder follow a curve but it won't stay straight in the middle.

Comment: You can probably fix this by adding more control points to the curve, and then adjusting them to  your needs. An easy way to add more points where you need them is to select the two points on "either side" of the desired area, right-click and select "subdivide".

Comment: So i basically i make more loop cuts with "subdivide" option and then i have to ajust those loop cuts manually until i get the straight surface i want? @ChristopherBennett

Comment: I'm not entirely sure of the details for a setup, but for a simple bezier curve, yes, that's the way I'd do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you could do is select all the part that is supposed to be flat:

[image]

Remove it:

[image]

Then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> *> Bridge Edge Loops* and tweak the number of cuts in the *Operator* box:

[image]